# Docker compose image upgrade

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose image running:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:commit1
  service:
    image: service:commit1
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The image has a tag of commit id of git. If anything changes in code, CI/CD pipeline runs and updates the image with latest commit id.

Now let's say I have images as:
`postgres:commit2` and `service:commit2`.

What is the best procedure to update the images given the containers are running using commit1 in the compose file?

Do I need to update the images manually in compose and then:

```
docker-compose restart
```

And remove the other containers manually?

Is it the best way?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to templatize your compose file and have a separate CI/CD step to generate a new file with the new image tags on every build.

For ex. -

```
// docker-compose.yml.template

version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:{{ COMMIT_ID }}
  service:
    image: service:{{ COMMIT_ID }}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and a using `sed` or `awk` script you can replace `{{ COMMIT_ID }}` with the latest commit id and generate the new file.

```
// docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:commit2
  service:
    image: service:commit2
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Then you can finally pull and use latest images using `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for some option to do rolling update  with docker-compose and your service support multiple instances. This can be achieved by, first changing the image id in docker-compose file, you can use your CI/CD tool to create new docker-compose file with updated commit hash.

Then you can use below command add new containers(with new new image) behind the services.

```
docker-compose up --scale db=1 --scale service=1 --no-recreate
```

Then next step would be to delete the old containers

```
   docker rm old-container # service
```

Then the last step would be to scale the services to the number of instances you want.

This is the best I can think of for just docker-compose. If you were using docker swarm or any other system it would have been out of box feature :)